# Validate jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

I know this is a repeated questions but all previously asked question's answer did not worked for me.

I've used this widget but after applying it to all `dropdown` I'm not being able to validate this new `multiselect dropdown`.

### HTML

```
<td style="width: 20%; text-align: right;" class="LabelText">
    Select Period* :
</td>
<td style="text-align: left; width: 30%" class="LabelText">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStudyPeriod" runat="server" Width="40px" multiple="multiple">
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

### JavaScript

```
function fnValidateStudy() {
    var options = $('#ddlStudyPeriod > option:selected');
    debugger;
    if (options.length == 0) {

        alert("Please Select Period");
        return false;
    }
```

But this does not work. Even if I've selected values in widget's `dropdown` its showing blank array in console or `0` length.

I want to check that either any value is selected for `dropdown` or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
 var options = $("#ddlStudyPeriod option:selected").length;
        if (options == 0) {
            alert('Please select Period');
            return false;
        }
```